# Override ESAPI OWASP methods java

Tags: owasp, esapi

I am trying to override an existing method in ESAPI OWASP library, by using [ESAPI.override()](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/ESAPI.html#override%28org.owasp.esapi.SecurityConfiguration%29). Somehow it does not work, do you know why?

Here my code:

```
public class AntiSamyDOMScannerExpansion extends AbstractAntiSamyScanner {

//...
public CleanResults scan(String html, String inputEncoding, String outputEncoding) throws ScanException {
        ESAPI.override(new DefaultSecurityConfiguration());
//...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ESAPI.override()` is used only to override the configuration. In order to expand other kind of methods, in my case `AntiSamy.scan`, it is needed to extend every class in the call structure.
This is because of a inflexible implementation. For instance we find in `HTMLValidationRule.java`:

```
private String invokeAntiSamy( String context, String input ) throws ValidationException {
        // CHECKME should this allow empty Strings? "   " us IsBlank instead?
        if ( StringUtilities.isEmpty(input) ) {
            if (allowNull) {
                return null;
            }
            throw new ValidationException( context + " is required", "AntiSamy validation error: context=" + context + ", input=" + input, context );
        }

        String canonical = super.getValid( context, input );

        try {
            AntiSamy as = new AntiSamy();
            CleanResults test = as.scan(canonical, antiSamyPolicy);

            List<String> errors = test.getErrorMessages();
            if ( !errors.isEmpty() ) {
                LOGGER.info( Logger.SECURITY_FAILURE, "Cleaned up invalid HTML input: " + errors );
            }

            return test.getCleanHTML().trim();

        } catch (ScanException e) {
            throw new ValidationException( context + ": Invalid HTML input", "Invalid HTML input: context=" + context + " error=" + e.getMessage(), e, context );
        } catch (PolicyException e) {
            throw new ValidationException( context + ": Invalid HTML input", "Invalid HTML input does not follow rules in antisamy-esapi.xml: context=" + context + " error=" + e.getMessage(), e, context );
        }
    }
```

Due to `AntiSamy as = new AntiSamy();` we can not make it usable in a custom implementation.